# Callback exception [TypeError: listener must be a function]

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, child-process

I have written a simple NodeJS program to execute a shell script. I fork out a child and try to execute the script. I have provided a callback to the child on exit as shown below. But it is throwing an exception when I try to run the program. Where am I going wrong?

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

function callXmlAgent(callback) {
    try {
        var child = exec('./a.sh');
        var response = { stdout: '', stderr: '', errCode: -1 };

        child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
            response.stdout += data;
        });

        child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
            response.stderr += data;
        });

        child.on('close', function (errCode) {
            if (errCode) {
                response.errCode = errCode;
            }
        });

        child.on('exit', callback(response));

        process.on('exit', function () {
            // If by chance the parent exits, the child is killed instantly
            child.kill();
        });
    } catch(exception) {
        console.log(exception);
    }
}

function foo(response) {
    console.log(response)
};

callXmlAgent(foo);
```

The output I get is:

```
{ stdout: '', stderr: '', errCode: -1 }
[TypeError: listener must be a function]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modify the child exit event with the following code:

```
child.on('exit', function() {
   callback(response);
});
```

Now it doesn't throw an error anymore, but be aware that working with asynchronous data does not guarantee you the order of execution, so you might have unexpected results.

The problem is that you cannot pass a function with parameters within another function. You have to create an anonymous function and send the parameters inside of it.

Comment: Yes. It does seem to do away with the exception. But what was the problem? Was it expecting a function with a particular signature?

Comment: @honk: thank you, I already did it. I am new to stackoverflow ;)

Comment: @andresigualada: That is a very good contribution, thank you! As long as you feel new, just visit the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read a few paragraphs each day. This will help you to become familiar with Stack Overflow quickly.